# R - Outer product of two vectors, using custom FUN to return lists

Tags: r, vector

I have two sequences which I'm trying to combine using an outer join but returning lists

For example,

```
s1 <- seq(1,3)
s2 <- seq(4,6)
```

and I'm trying to end up with a matrix of lists like this:

```
c(1,4)c(2,4)c(3,4)
c(1,5)c(2,5)c(3,5)
c(1,6)c(2,6)c(3,6)
```

so I'm trying to use the outer product function with a custom function

```
listify <- function(a,b){
   lst <- cbind(a,b)
 }

outer(h1,h2,FUN = "listify")
```

which should be doing what I want but I can't seem to get it to work. I've read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554305/simple-question-regarding-the-use-of-outer-and-user-defined-functions) which suggests the usage of cbind, but as I said, I've gotten no results. I just get an error:

```
Error in dim(robj) <- c(dX, dY) : 
  dims [product 121] do not match the length of object [242]
```

Comment: What are you calling "lists"? Do you mean vectors? Wouldn't just `expand.grid(s1, s2)` work? Also, I don't see any "outer product" here.

Comment: I think OP is asking for a larger version of `matrix(list(c(1, 4), c(1, 5), c(1, 6), c(2, 4), c(2, 5), c(2, 6)), ncol = 3)` as output. My question is *why?* It seem like either a long 2-d `expand.grid` style answer or a 3-d array would fit the data better. What's the benefit of using a `matrix` to hold the result?

Comment: @DavidArenburg well the main reason I'm not using expand.grid is I didn't know about it. Know that I do, I will use that. Thank you both

Comment: Given that `expand.grid` was the right answer, I think this is a dupe (now closed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can get pretty close (or maybe all the way there?) (a) making your function return a `list`, and (b) vectorizing it. From `?outer`

> `FUN`... must be a vectorized function (or the name of one) expecting at least two arguments and returning a value with the same length as the first (and the second).

```
listify <- function(a,b){
   list(a,b)
}

lv = Vectorize(listify)

s1 <- seq(1,3)
s2 <- seq(4,6)

result = t(outer(s1,s2,FUN = lv))
result
#      [,1]      [,2]      [,3]     
# [1,] Integer,2 Integer,2 Integer,2
# [2,] Integer,2 Integer,2 Integer,2
# [3,] Integer,2 Integer,2 Integer,2

result[1, 1]
# [[1]]
#      a b
# [1,] 1 4

result[2, 1]
# [[1]]
#      a b
# [1,] 1 5
```

Note that each element of the matrix is a list of length 1.

As pointed out in comments, without more info I don't see any advantage of having these single-element lists in a matrix. A long-form `expand.grid` table or a 3-d array both seem potentially easier to work with.

Comment: The correct answer is just use expand.grid. I just didn't know about it, thanks! I'm not sure if the rest works